# Связь через веб-интерфейс с GSM

Tags: веб-программирование

Здравствуйте. Есть задача: организовать связь "компьютер - GSM телефон". Точнее даже не телефон, а GPS-трекер с поддержкой GSM. На той стороне это сделано. А вот со стороны веб-браузера не представляю. Какая аппаратура потребуется и сложно ли это реализовать?

В нем стоит сим-карта и подключается трубка. С мобильного телефона можно позвонить на эту симку и разговаривать. Но нужно из веб-приложения обеспечить связь, т.е. через микрофон компьютера. Это диспетчерское приложение слежения за транспортом. Нужно, чтоб по клику можно было позвонить.

Comment: Можно подробнее описать схему взаимодействия? Общую картину.

Comment: C gps трекера отсылается информация на сервер. На сервере уже эта информация обрабатывается и показывается пользователю.

Comment: @lampa, это GPS-координаты так работают. Не в них суть. В нем стоит сим-карта и подключается трубка. С мобильного телефона можно позвонить на эту симку и разговаривать. Но нужно из веб-приложения обеспечить связь, т.е. через микрофон компьютера.

Comment: @Андрей Бакша если универсально - то звонок через skype. А так обычный gsm модуль для ПК. Или я неправильно понял задачу?

Comment: @lampa, да-да правильно. Через скайп - дорого (Беларусь) и не веб-интерфейс. А про Gsm-модуль для ПК ничего не слышал, поэтому и задал вопрос) Нужно будет поискать.

Comment: VoIP должно быть сильно дешевле скайпа, при больших объемах там могут быть серьезные скидки...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как говорилось в мультфильме Саус Парк: "Сын мой, я не касался бы этого даже двенадцатифутовой палкой".
И вот почему:
во-1, тарифные пакеты для передачи голоса и данных весьма разные по цене, и в итоге комплексный пакет данные+голос взвинтит абонплату за передачу до небес.
во-2, задача трекера - передача дискретной малообъемной геоинформации. все.

Один из моих проектов -- поддержка и развитие веб-сервиса для системы спутникового монитиринга на транспорте. У нас были клиенты, которые хотели заставить трекер говорить и даже впихнуть скрытый микрофон в кабину, чтобы дополнительно контролировать водителя - но после тестирования прототипов стало предельно ясно, что такой комплекс сделать возможно, но он будет стоить НЕПОМЕРНО дорого в обслуживании и качество голосового сигнала будет КАТЕГОРИЧНО отвратным.

Comment: @devian, спасибо за развернутый проект. Сейчас стоит такая же задача - мониторинг транспорта. Заказчики хотят такую связь с водителями и отговорить не получается.

Comment: @Андрей Бакша скорее всего придется всё самому копать и запасаться голдой на ПО. По сути как это должно работать: на сайте флеш, на сервере аудиосервер, связанный каким-то образом с GSM модулем. Аудиосервер и привязку модуля врятли осилите, тут на фриланс. Мне так писали модуль вместо транскодера для вовзы.

Comment: "убеждайте, обосновывайте, запугивайте..." :) сошлитесь на мой опыт, попытайтесь объяснить заказчикам что специалисты уже пытались сделать подобное, потратили силы и средства, - и в итоге вышли на то, что проще всего диспетчеру звонить на мобильный водителю обычным образом :)

Comment: @deivan, будем пугать затратами)
@lampa, да вряд ли флеш + аудиосервер потянем.